# iBeacon work flow Clarification

Tags: ibeacon, ibeacon-android, beacon

My Understand for iBeacon : Beacons are scan using by UUID in iOS. But in Android able to scan without UUID.

Clarification : I have searched more things in internet and stack overflow for beacons are scan  without uuid. But most of them said must have UUID to scan the beacon in iOS. But all of them in before 2015. I don't knw right now(2016) apple update anything do scan without UUID.
Android able to scan without UUID.

Please any one confirm beacons are scan based on UUID using by ibeacon in iOS. Each application have only one UUID for all beacons. We define the differences the beacons in major and minor values.

If i set UUID for multiple beacons able to search in iOS using by ibeacon?

Below reference link counld't to without UUID. Any possible way is there for scan without UUID ?

Ref:
http://www.ibeacon.com/what-is-ibeacon-a-guide-to-beacons/

https://developer.apple.com/ibeacon/Getting-Started-with-iBeacon.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS, you **must know the ProximityUUID of a beacon in advance** in order to scan for it using CoreLocation.  This has not changed since iBeacon was announced by Apple three years ago.  You must know this because the CoreLication scanning APIs require you to specify the UUID to look for when starting beacon ranging or monitoring.  It may not be left nil or wildcarded with public APIs.

This restriction does not apply to other beacon formats like AltBeacon and Eddystone, whose full identifiers can be read without knowing any part of them in advance.  This is possible with these beacon formats because they use CoreBluetooth to do the scanning, not CoreLocation.  CoreLocation is what requires the UUID up front, and Apple blocks iBeacon scanning with CoreBluetooth.

Comment: What is the identifier in  initWithProximityUUID ? Can you please give some example

Comment: [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"124C5678-4444-1111-2222-134556728422"];

Comment: Thanks for your answer . One more clarification . Some other user have ibeacon near me with same UUID(Which is i'm using  in my ibeacon). If i search app show both beacons? if means how i will find my beacon ?Please answer

Comment: Davidyoung where we map the identifier with beacons ?

Comment: The only way to know your own beacons from those belonging to somebody else it to make the identifiers unique so they are distinguishable.  If somebody else is sharing the UUID, then your probably can't discern the difference unless you can guarantee you won't have major/minor overlap.  There is no other trick -- sorry.